# Twilio - unhold participant when connecting to a conference room

Tags: twilio

I hold conference participant using the next functionlity:

```
$POST /Conference/{ConferenceSid}/Participants/{ParticipantsSid}
-d "Hold=True" \
-d "HoldUrl={HoldUrl}" \
-u 'AC123:{AuthToken}'
```

Will Twilio unhold participant when I redirect him to the new or to the same(current) conference room with Dial Conference functionality? Or do I have to unhold participant after/before he was redirected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When the caller enters a new conference because they are redirected, they will be a new Participant and have a new SID, so will not be on Hold.

If you have a [Participant on hold in one conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/conference-participant#place-a-participant-on-hold) and you want them to stay in the same conference but come off hold, then I would just bring them off hold rather than redirect them:

```
$POST /Conference/{ConferenceSid}/Participants/{ParticipantsSid} -d "Hold=False"
```